# Shell Script to read a line in a file and replace with value in property file

Tags: shell, sh

I have a file names.txt and it has multiple lines of names, like below:

tom
sam
harry
sarrah

and I have a property file which has equivalent value for few names, like below:

tom=tommy
sam=samantha

I have to read each line of file names.txt and if **sam or tom** found, It has to replace with value from property file and my end result should be like below:

tommy
samantha
harry
sarrah

Please help me in identifying the script for the same

Comment: What should it do with the name "samuel" ? Make sure you have a test case for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not super robust, but you could do:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} 
    { print $0 in a ? a[$0] : $0}' properties names.txt
```

Comment: A bit terse, but here's an explanation: With `NR==FNR { ... }` we read all keys from `properties` into a  hash `a`;  the print statement should be read as `print ($0 in a) ? ... `, saying if the current line matches a key in the hash, print its matching value `a[$0]`, else print the original line `$0`

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if you got your answer or not but I am posting one script which will do your task. The inputs to the script are namefile and propertyfil.

```
filenm=$1       --Name file as input
lkfilenm=$2     --Property file for lookup

while read line
do

echo $line

z=`grep "$line" /home/$lkfilenm | cut -d"=" -f2`

echo $z

if [ -z "$z" ]; then       
    echo ok
else       
    sed -e "s/$line/$z/g" /home/$filenm > filenme
fi

done<$filenm

mv filenme $filenm
rm -f filenme
```

Execution: Fire the below command to execute the shell:

```
ksh script.ksh namefile prptyfile
```